# Android - how to display Android OS version

Tags: android, operating-system

I would like to display the android OS version, like Jellybean, cupcake etc. How would i go about doing that. I know you can use the Build.Version_Codes but not entirely sure how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
    android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Please look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Comment: Yeah I saw these. But without having to manually creating a case statement for each, is there any way of corresponding and outputting the name?

Comment: there are all versions at android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES ut I don´t think You could get them as a string.